# No python executable could be found on your system , Titanium

Tags: module, titanium

I am using eclipse to make titanium module, but whenever I use Ant build i get error

> No python executable could be found on your system

i have installed

Titanium SDK.
All of the prerequisites for developing Android applications.
Android NDK. Add an ANDROID_NDK environment variable pointing to the NDK folder.
Eclipse and ADT.
gperf e installed and in your system PATH.

I also checked my bulid.properties which is like this:

`titanium.platform=C:\\Users\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\3.1.1.GA\\android`
`android.platform=C:\\AndroidSDK\\platforms\\android-10`
`google.apis=C:\\AndroidSDK\\add-ons\\addon-google_apis-google-10`
`android.ndk = C:\\android-ndk-r9`

What is wrong with mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this and it works for me ;)

first i have installed python 2.7 and chnage the path variable to

> C:\Python27

then change the JDK in eclipse path :

1) In Eclipse click Run->External Tools->External Tools Configurations
2) Click JRE tab
3) Click Installed JREs... button
4) Click Add button (select Standard VM, where applicable)
5) Click Directory Button
6) Browse to your JDK version (not JRE) of your installed Java (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25)
7) Click Finish.

Answer (score 0):

Accordint to [this page](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Installing_Python) Python is required for compiling from the commandline (which I guess would be how Ant invokes it). So if you need that you need to install Python 2.7 which is available from [their website](http://www.python.org/download/).